# how do I solve following differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dx}{z(x+y)}=\frac{dy}{z(x-y)}=\frac{dz}{x^2+y^2}$

How do I solve this equation I am not getting it can someone help?please

Comment: Do you want all $z$s to be the same size?

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: It is not a single "this equation" but a system of equations involving differentials, unless perhaps there is a typo?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dx}{x+y}=\frac{dy}{x-y}=\frac{z\,dz}{x^2+y^2}$

I suppose this set of equations comes from a PDE solved thanks to the method of characteristics.

A first characteristic curve is obtained from :

$\frac{dx}{z(x+y)}=\frac{dy}{z(x-y)} \quad\to\quad (y-x)dx+(x+y)dy=0 \quad\to\quad y^2-x^2-2xy=c_1$

A second characteristic curve is obtained from :

$\frac{ydx}{y(x+y)}=\frac{xdy}{x(x-y)}=\frac{ydx+xdy}{y(x+y)+x(x-y)}=\frac{xdy+ydx}{y^2+x^2}$

$\frac{dx}{x+y}=\frac{dy}{x-y}=\frac{z\,dz}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{xdy+ydx}{y^2+x^2}$

$z\,dz=xdy+ydx=d(xy) \quad\to\quad \frac{z^2}{2xy}=c_2$